# How to grow file system from inside the docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-container, aws-batch

I have an container running on aws batch on an instance running on 2 disks, I modified the size of one of them to 1000GB, then I grow the partition size and file system of the host using `growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1` and `xfs_growfs /dev/nvme0n1p1`
Now running `lsblk` from the container returns

```
nvme1n1 259:0 0 558.8G 0 disk /st
nvme0n1 259:1 0 1000G 0 disk
|-nvme0n1p1 259:2 0 1000G 0 part /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cbl.so.470.57.02
`-nvme0n1p128 259:3 0 1M 0 part
```

so far so good. However  `df -h` from the container returns

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay 100G 15G 86G 15% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1 100G 15G 86G 15% /storage
/dev/nvme1n1 559G 603M 558G 1% /st
...
```

How can I expand the `/storage` from inside the container, or is there a way to unmount and remount from inside the container?

Comment: In general, a Docker container is prohibited from having direct access to host devices and from mounting and unmounting filesystems.  You need to run these sorts of system-administration tasks from the host system.

Comment: I have a named pipe connecting container to host, that's how I was able to resize the disk and filesystem in host